# Pass temporary ENV variables to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

There are times where I'd like my Heroku console to do something differently but only for that instance. While I'm able to control this through command line arguments it can get a little long/messy.

I'm trying to pass temporary ENV vars to Heroku when booting a console but am so far unable to. I'd like to run `SOME_VAR=some_value heroku run console --app myapp` but once Rails boots, I do not have `ENV['SOME_VAR']`.

I know I can set this and then delete it from the Heroku website but that restarts the server which I'd like to avoid.

## tl;dr

Is there a way to pass temporary `ENV` vars to Rails apps running on Heroku without setting them in the Heroku dashboard?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You must set the variable AFTER `heroku run`:

```
heroku run MYVAR=hello rails console
```

Once you're connected, you can verify that MYVAR is set:

```
puts ENV['MYVAR']
=> "hello"
```

Comment: Thank you! I must have forgotten somewhere along the way that `heroku run console` was a shortcut or alias for `heroku run rails console` and that ENV vars could be put in there.

Answer (score 5):

Lately I've been unable to pass in variables as strings that include spaces. What worked is the following:

```sh
heroku run rails c -a my-app -e "ONE=my first var;TWO=another one"
```

The `-e` flag is lightly documented [in the docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-run).